# Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwxgtk3.2-1 (>=3.2.0) when trying to update PWSafe from V1.13 to V1.18.2

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, gdebi

I downloaded passwordsafe-ubuntu23-1.18.2-amd64.deb from sourceforge.net - the official site and tried to install it using Software Install, but no go.

Learned about and installed gdebi and tried to use that to install it and got -
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwxgtk3.2-1 (>=3.2.0)

Does this suggest a problem with .deb file/package?

Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Package issues are specific to releases, and you've not told us yours. Are you hoping we guess?  Why not tell us.  eg. I see `libwxgtk3.2-1 | 3.2.2+dfsg-4        | mantic/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available for *mantic* or 23.10 which meets the requirements...

Comment: @MitcheCA Please do not "downloaded [...].deb from sourceforge.net". We will not support that. Please try `sudo apt install passwordsafe`.

Comment: @Daniel T did that and was told that passwordsafe V1.13, which I have, is the latest version, but I am aware of V1.18.2. When will what you have suggested update to V1.18.2?

Comment: @guiverc will enabling the Universe repository lead to a different outcome when doing what Daniel T has suggested?

Comment: Adding the *universe* repository will just allow you to use the community sourced packages of Ubuntu; if you re-read my first comment, you'll note the package I mentioned is found in *mantic/universe* meaning you need to be using Ubuntu *mantic* (ie. 23.10) and have *universe* enabled for that package. Ubuntu 23.10 is the *latest stable* release of Ubuntu, as I said first comment you've not told us your release, so we cannot know what you'll have available as we don't know what you're using. Using 3rd party software means security checks are on you to perform (it's your choice to use them)

Comment: @MitcheCA I don't know where 1.13 is from. I only see 1.12 and 1.16. You can see the versions for each Ubuntu release at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=passwordsafe . Each Ubuntu release is tested with and will stay at one major version. This makes things reliable and ensures that you don't break your system. If you want 1.17, then update to 23.10. Considering the fact that 1.18 isn't even in Debian sid, I expect 24.10 or 25.04 will have it.

Comment: Despite advise not to download I did so from sourceforge.net and installed from that download. 
Prior to download, i.e. using sudo apt install passwordsafe I had PWsafe V1.13 after download and install I now have PWsafe V1.18.2, which so far has worked as expected.
Thanks to all who have contributed to this.